# PhoneGap Build Config.xml BundleVersion

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, phonegap-build, ipa

I'm trying to create a new build of my JS app on PhoneGap Build but I'm having trouble with the iOS BundleVersion and BundleShortVersionString.

The system used to do this for me with the "version" field on PhoneGap settings, but since I added a config.xml file to add spash images and icons it no longer creates the versions so XCode doesn't accept my .ipa files.

This is currently what I have on my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.15" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget version="1.15" ios-CFBundleVersion="1.15" ios-CFBundleShortVersionString="1.15">

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>App Name</name>

<description>
    My App decription. 
</description>

<author href="http://website.com" email="email@example.com">
    Author. 
</author>

<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />

<platform name="ios">
          <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
          <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
          <icon src="icons/_mark-152x152.png" width="152" height="152" />
          <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
          <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
          <icon src="icons/_mark-152x152" width="120" height="120" />
          <!-- iPad -->
          <icon src="icons/_mark-152x152" width="76" height="76" />
 </platform>
<platform name="android">
          <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
          <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
          <icon src="icons/_mark-152x152.png" width="152" height="152" />
          <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
          <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
          <icon src="icons/_mark-152x152" width="120" height="120" />
          <!-- iPad -->
          <icon src="icons/_mark-152x152" width="76" height="76" />
 </platform>
```

This was the solution I found on google, but it's not working... Also unpacking the .ipa and modifying it by hand doesn't work either, it gets kicked back by XCode. Also, my config.xml file is working fine except for this, it's currently placed on the index of my app folder, on the same level as index.html.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/invalid-pre-release-train#reply_16398844

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastian,
This question has been answer multiple times on [Nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi), the official forum for *Phonegap Build*.

The answer is, add the following to your `config.xml`

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>101</string>
</gap:config-file>
```

Replace the number `101` with your version number.

The documentation you need is at [Documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/) -> Configuring -> [Config File Elements](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements) -> [iOS](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#_ios)

Here are two (2) threads that talk about the subject.

[invalid pre-release train](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/invalid-pre-release-train#reply_16398844) - 11 days ago

[CFBundleShortVersionString missing error when submitting app to Store (iOS)](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/cfbundleshortversionstring-missing-error-when-submitting-app-to-store-ios) - 1 year ago.